# HTML5 video issue on the android tablet

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have a problem with playing some video in android tablet(chrome browser).

I have a website and when i clicked on banner there is popup that need to play some video.

In pc everything is ok! but when i tried it in my tablet its not working. I know the autoplay isn't working in tablets or something like that, therfore i'm using play() and load() but it still not working. In addition i have at the same popup button that open lightbox, at this lightbox there is close button. The weird thing is happen when i'm click this button and then the video start to play.

I wrote function that run when the popup window is loading, here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function load() {
        $('#videoDiv').show();
        var a = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
        var adVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
        var adVideoSrc = document.getElementById('video_player_source');
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * ads.length));
        $(adVideoSrc).attr('src', ads[x]);
        adVideoPlayer.load();
        adVideoPlayer.play();


         // when the ad is finish, play another video.
        $('#videoPlayer').bind("ended", setNewVideo);
        function setNewVideo(e) {

            $("#commercialButton").hide();
            $('#pCommerial').text('');
            //$(adVideoSrc).attr('src', a);
            //document.getElementById('htmlFive').setAttribute('poster','newvalue');
          $(adVideoSrc).attr('src', a);
          adVideoPlayer.setAttribute("controls","controls");
          adVideoPlayer.load();
        }
} 
</script>
```

The onload func:

```
<body onload="load()">
all the code is here....
</body>
```

Here is the code of the video player:

```
        <video id="videoPlayer" width="510" height="287">           
            <source id="video_player_source" src="" type="video/mp4" </source>
        </video>
```

And here is the event when i push on the close button:
At this code i'm only use play() method again and suddenly it works for some reason.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function videoResetFields(){
                window.resizeBy(0, -318);
                var adVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
                adVideoPlayer.play();
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#comments').val('');
                $('#fullName').val('');
                $('#telephone').val('');
            }               
            </script>
```

Comment: Can you put it in a fiddle please.

Comment: Sorry, what is fiddle?

Comment: http://www.jfiddle.net/
This is website where you post your code to show to us and so we can test on and save and show you afterwards.

Comment: Ok thanks an its - http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: oh yeh forgot the s :P

Comment: I can't wrote it there its complicated and you dont understand nothing. The problem explained well i think..